# Cross-domain saving file uploaded by user

Tags: php, image, cross-domain, uploading, cookieless

I have a website [example.com](http://example.com) where people can upload images. But I want to have those images saved in my cookieless domain [examplestatic.com](http://examplestatic.com). So, I wrote:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $folder_temp .$image_path_1 );
```

where folder temp is:
www.examplestatic.com/image_folder/big_images

However, I get an error that it can't move the file. I used to have it move the uploaded files to a folder in the same domain and it would work. But since I changed the directory of $folder_temp to the new static domain, it doesn't work anymore. How can I allow users to upload files cross-domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to it:

It's uploading the file via FTP using php. The code goes like this:

```
$ftp_server = "server";
$ftp_username  = "username";
$ftp_password   =  "password";
$connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");
if(@ftp_login($connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{ ftp_put($connection, $folder_destination, $location_original_file, FTP_BINARY) or die("could not find directory");
} else { }
ftp_close($connection);
```

It took me a big while to figure out unexpected errors that were showing up. So a few things to keep in mind: 
1) Make sure the $folder_destination is the directory INSIDE the folder assigned to the ftp user you create. 
2) The `$location_original_file` has to be the directory where the picture is saved (same directory that you would reference a picture to in your php code). 
3) FTP_ASCII doesn't work for pictures. It has to be FTP_BINARY (at least it FTP_ASCII didn't work for me); And finally, make sure all folders that you have to access using ftp have writable permissions.
4) For some reasons, ftp_put could not read the uploaded file. I have no idea why. It's like when I open the ftp connection, it loses the file uploaded by the user. So, what I did is save the file on a directory in the same domain first, before even opening the ftp connection (I did this last), then I moved the saved file to the other domain. I needed to move a few versions of the uploaded picture modified so I did all the modifications first, saved the modified versions on the same domain, then moved all those saved files to their respective directories in the new domain.

That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the uploaded file to a folder on your server and then changed your web server configuration to have your other domain point to a directory where that folder is accessible.